# Error with executing Python files in cgi-bin (have tried enabling CGI Scripts in Apache)

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, cgi-bin

I have a running Apache2 server on Ubuntu, with PHP installed.
My root folder is `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`.

I have put a test python script in `/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin`, named `test.py`.

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
print 'hi'
```

I access this in the browser via `http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py`.  At the moment, it just displays the Python code that I just typed out, rather than executing it.  I have looked extensively at online documentations and other stackoverflow questions that address this issue.

From that research I changed my `httpd.conf` file to include a few `Directory`'s.

**httpd.conf** (stuff added to end of it)

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2">
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have restarted/hard-started/stopped Apache and was able to run the Python file successfully through the command-line, but still no luck with actually executing the python file through the browser.  I have even checked the Apache error log, but saw no indication of the problem. Can anyone offer some advice?

Thank you

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: In the context of this problem it's not relevant, but eventually I'll be executing (via `exec`) the python script in a PHP page.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to chmod 755 cgi-bin folder(and/or subfolder) where you script is.

Then chmod 755 your script file.

and finally..

Open script in notepad of your preference and save with encoding UTF-8 without BOM, and EOL(end of line) conversion must be set for UNIX systems. (in Notepad++ latter is in Edit menu)